# How to fix form elements (radio / checkbox / date) from appearing below the hidden menu bar

Tags: html, css, forms

So i have to make a website for my class, part of it is doing enhancements so i thought id make a hidden menu (with the hamburger icon thingy)
It works all well and good, except on my form page when i click the hamburger, the menu covers the page except the little radio and checkbox etc show through.
I have attached images showing what should happen [on all the other pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6f49.png)
and what does happen [on my form page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29zH7.png)

```css
.logo,
.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

label.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 7px 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: blueviolet;
  transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:952px) {
  label.logo {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:2000px) {
  .checkbtn {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #2d0858;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .menu a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: blueviolet;
  }
  #check:checked~ul {
    left: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn"> &#8801; </label>
  <label class="logo"> PeakIT </label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a id="home" href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
    <li><a id="about" href="about.html">About Me </a></li>
    <li><a id="apply" href="apply.html"> Apply now</a> </li>
    <li><a id="jobs" href="jobs.html">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a id="enhancements" href="enhancements.html">Enhancements</a></li>
    <li><a id="contact" href=mailto:104467971@student.swin.edu.au> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Honestly im at a complete loss. I tried googling but most says to use JS and we arent allowed, any help is appreciated thanks :)

Comment: I tried this out and it seems to work fine for me. Please check if you have used `z-index` anywhere, and if you have make sure you give a `z-index` with a higher value for your `navbar`

Answer (score 0):

Please set z-index on the nav to an appropriate (high) value. Specifically, you will need to change the styles to something like

```
nav {
  /* maintain existing styles as such but add this property setting */
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still hasn't worked unfortunately

Comment: I got it, i had to add the z index onto the nav ul line where it states the position is fixed. Thank you so much!